# How can I move desktop icons freely in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

Just been upgraded to Windows 7. How do I move the Desktop icons freely and how can I place them where I like?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have "auto arrange" set.

Try this: right click on the desktop and click "View" from the resulting menu.  Then uncheck "auto-arrange icons"  You should now be able to move the icons freely.

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking "align icons to grid"

Comment: Can you expand upon this? Thanks.